# Узнать количество элементов в sql с помощью cursor

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

В Android приложении имеется SQL-бд.

Задача - получить рандомную запись с помощью класса Random.

Алгоритм:

1. Делаем необходимый запрос к бд
2. Получаем количество записей после запроса
3. Генерируем случайное число
4. Перемещаемся на случайную запись
5. Забираем ее

   ```
       if(countQuestion!=0){

           Cursor cursor = db.query(EgeDBHelper.QUESTIONS_TABLE, new String[]{EgeDBHelper.COLUMN_ID, EgeDBHelper.LESSON_ID, EgeDBHelper.QUESTION_TYPE, EgeDBHelper.QUESTION},
                   EgeDBHelper.LESSON_ID+"='"+id.toString()+"' AND "+EgeDBHelper.QUESTION_TYPE+"='"+(i+1)+"'", 
                   null, null, null, null);//Запрос

           for(int j = 0; j < countQuestion; j++){
               int a = random.nextInt(cursor.getCount());
               cursor.move(a);
               Log.d("Random", String.valueOf(a)+" "+String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
               int questionID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EgeDBHelper.COLUMN_ID));
               questions.add(new Question(questionID, db));
           }
           cursor.close();
       }

   }
   ```

Компилятор выдает:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 42 requested, with a size of 42
```

Логи:

```
D/Random: 30 42
D/Random: 27 42
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете не тот метод для установки курсора на позицию.

Метод [`move`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#move(int)) перемещает курсор на переданное в виде аргумента число позиций от текущего положения, а не устанавливает на указанную позицию.

Вам нужен метод [`moveToPosition`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition(int))

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал

Comment: Пожалуйста) Я сам не знал, пока в доки не заглянул)